# tkinter searchbox for treeview python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So I want to make a simple inventory system CRUD program. So far, I have been able to make it able to add new items, modify them and delete them. I'm lacking one last thing and that is to be able to search from a treeview which shows all of the items from the sqlite3 database. I wish to have a search box where i could just type in the name of the item and the program will print and select the items searched, which then i could do things such as modify or delete the selected items.

So far my code is:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, PhotoImage, Label, LabelFrame, W, E, N, S, Entry, END, StringVar, Scrollbar, Toplevel
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3



class Inventory:
    db_filename = 'stock.db'
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.create_gui()
        ttk.style = ttk.Style()
        ttk.style.configure('Treeview', font=('helvetica',10))
        ttk.style.configure('Treeview.Heading', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))

    def execute_db_query(self, query, parameters=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_filename) as conn:
            print(conn)
            print('You have successfully connected to the Database')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query_result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return query_result

    def create_gui(self):
        self.create_left_icon()
        self.create_label_frame()
        self.create_message_area()
        self.create_tree_view()
        self.create_scrollbar()
        self.create_bottom_buttons()
        self.view_items()

    def create_left_icon(self):
        photo = PhotoImage(file='./icons/logo.png')
        label = Label(image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def create_label_frame(self):
        labelframe = LabelFrame(self.root, text='Input New Items', bg='sky blue', font='helvetica 10')
        labelframe.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=8, pady=8, sticky='ew')
        Label(labelframe, text='Name of Item:', bg='sky blue', fg='black').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2, padx=15)
        self.typefield = Entry(labelframe)
        self.typefield.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=2)
        Label(labelframe, text='Stock Card ID:', bg='sky blue', fg='black').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2, padx=15)
        self.cardfield = Entry(labelframe)
        self.cardfield.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=2)
        Label(labelframe, text='Count:', bg='sky blue', fg='black').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2, padx=15)
        self.countfield = Entry(labelframe)
        self.countfield.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=2)
        Button(labelframe, text='Add', command=self.on_add_item_button_clicked, fg='black').grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

    def create_message_area(self):
        self.message = Label(text='', fg='red')
        self.message.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

    def create_tree_view(self):
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=('card', 'stock'), style='Treeview')
        self.tree.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Name of Item', anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading('card', text='Stock Card ID', anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading('stock', text='Count', anchor=W)

    def create_scrollbar(self):
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=6, column=3, rowspan=10, sticky='sn')

    def create_bottom_buttons(self):
        Button(text='Delete', command=self.on_delete_selected_button_clicked).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10, padx=20)
        Button(text='Edit Stock', command=self.on_modify_selected_button_clicked).grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W)

    def on_add_item_button_clicked(self):
        self.add_new_item()

    def on_delete_selected_button_clicked(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Select at least one item to be deleted'
            return
        self.delete_items()

    def on_modify_selected_button_clicked(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except:
            self.message['text'] = 'Select at least one item to be modified'
            return
        self.open_modify_window()


    def add_new_item(self):
        if self.new_items_validated():
            query = 'INSERT INTO items_list VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.typefield.get(), self.cardfield.get(), self.countfield.get())
            self.execute_db_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = '{} has been added'.format(self.typefield.get())
            self.typefield.delete(0, END)
            self.cardfield.delete(0, END)
            self.countfield.delete(0, END)
            self.view_items()

        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'All entry field must be filled'
            self.view_items()

    def new_items_validated(self):
        return len(self.typefield.get()) !=0 and len(self.cardfield.get()) != 0 and len(self.countfield.get()) != 0

    def view_items(self):
        items = self.tree.get_children()
        for item in items:
            self.tree.delete(item)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM items_list ORDER BY TipeBarang'
        item_entries = self.execute_db_query(query)
        for row in item_entries:
            self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[1], values=(row[2], row[3]))

    def delete_items(self):
        self.message['text']=''
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM items_list WHERE TipeBarang = ?'
        self.execute_db_query(query, (name,))
        self.message['text'] = '{} has been deleted'.format(name)
        self.view_items()


    def open_modify_window(self):
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        old_stock = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
        self.transient = Toplevel()
        self.transient.title('Update Stock')
        Label(self.transient, text='Name: ').grid(row=0, column=1)
        Entry(self.transient, textvariable=StringVar(
            self.transient, value=name), state='readonly').grid(row=0, column=2)
        Label(self.transient, text='Old Stock Count: ').grid(row=1, column=1)
        Entry(self.transient, textvariable=StringVar(
            self.transient, value=old_stock), state='readonly').grid(row=1, column=2)

        Label(self.transient, text='New Stock Count: ').grid(row=2, column=1)
        new_stock_number_entry_widget = Entry(self.transient)
        new_stock_number_entry_widget.grid(row=2, column=2)

        Button(self.transient, text='Update Item', command=lambda: self.update_stock(
            new_stock_number_entry_widget.get(), old_stock, name)).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)

        self.transient.mainloop()

    def update_stock(self, newstock, old_stock, name):
        query = 'UPDATE items_list SET JumlahStok=? WHERE JumlahStok=? AND TipeBarang=?'
        parameters = (newstock, old_stock, name)
        self.execute_db_query(query, parameters)
        self.transient.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = '{} Stock Count has been updated'.format(name)
        self.view_items()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Inventory System")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    application = Inventory(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Below, I have also attached a screenshot of the program I have made so far. Thank you so much for your help.

Program Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kJch.png

Comment: What is your problem actually? Don't know how to search the treeview for specific content? Don't know how to add the search form into existing GUI? Or others?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways a search feature can be done here. You can add a search button that creates a [Toplevel window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) and add widgets to it as needed. Or more simply, you can use [simpledialog](https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm) to get text input from the user like so:

```
queryString = simpledialog.askstring("Search", "Enter item name to search:")
```

Then pass the resulting queryString to a database function, sanitize it to prevent SQL injection, and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Item = 'queryString'`

Then use the data returned from this query to populate your treeview.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Search():
    if SEARCH.get() != "":
        tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
        conn = sqlite3.connect("db_member.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `firstname` LIKE ? OR `lastname` LIKE ?", ('%'+str(SEARCH.get())+'%', '%'+str(SEARCH.get())+'%'))
        fetch = cursor.fetchall()
        for data in fetch:
            tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data))
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

this how you can search from Specific Column in Python with Sqlite3 and Tkinter, you have just to change tow things:

- the Name of 'member', which is the Name of your created Table
- firstname and lastname are the name of your columns, SEARCH.get() is the variable from the entry box